# Show this div and hide that div

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui, jquery, fancybox

Hello i want to know how can i modify my following js function to hide the content of one div and shows the content of the following div in the opened popup of fancybox the following div to show

```
<LI><A class="demo" id="example4" href="#demoView">Demo</A></LI> //linkfunctionality i want to show
<a id="various2" href="#divVideo" class="fl ml20"><img src="images/sites/img2.png" alt="" class="fl mr10" /></a> //Link functionality i want to hidde

<div style="display:none;">
    <div id="demoView">
        <div class="fl w900 pa20 bg2 tac">
            <h3 class="ff2 fwb fs30 mb10 cf3">Please contact us for a quick demo.</h3>
            <h4 class="ff2 fwb fs26 mb40 cf3">Email: <span  class="cf2 pr25"><a style="text-decoration:none; color:#2a98e2;" href="mailto:info@caremerge.com">info@caremerge.com</a></span> Call: <span class="cf2">(888) 996 6993</span></h4>
            <img src="images/sites/demo1.png" alt=""  class="dpib mb20"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The function below is successfully hiding the video but its not displaying the div mentioned above in it...

```
 function onPause() {

       froogaloop.addEvent('pause', function(data) {
                //$('a[href="#various2"]').fadeOut();
                $('#divVideo').fadeOut(500);
                // $('#various2').fadeOut(500);
                //$(' #demoView').fadeIn(500);
                $('#demoView').fadeIn();

                alert('ST-UCK');

       });
 }
```

**Some part of FANCY BOX JQUERY OF MY CODE**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {     

        $("a#example4").fancybox({
                'opacity'       : true,
                'overlayShow'   : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'none'
            });

        $("#various2").fancybox({
            'opacity'       : true,
                'overlayShow'   : false,
                'transitionIn'  : 'elastic',
                'transitionOut' : 'none',
                'onClosed'  :   function() {
                            document.getElementById('iframe-video');

                },
                'onStart'       :   function() {
                            //alert("hi");
                            //$('#banner-rotator').royalSlider({slideshowEnabled:false,slideshowDelay:20000 });
                }
        });
```

Comment: is there anyways to click up the div function by javascript like  $('#divAB7').clicked; // 
to accomplish the following funcionality same done:
 <a href="#divAB7" class="btn1 fl">Read More</a>

Comment: It looks like your `li` tag has non-`li` sibling elements. This would be invalid HTML if so; an `li` is the *only* valid child-element of a `ul` or `ol`, no other tags can be present *unless* they're wrapped inside of an `li`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open inline content in fancybox (either `#demoView` or `#divVideo` as in your example) the content is literally moved from its place in the *html* flow into the fancybox and a temporary `div` is left instead.

So when you opened `#divVideo` in fancybox, only that content is actually inside fancybox so this is why you can fade it out. You cannot fade `#demoView` in because it doesn't exist inside fancybox.

Maybe you just need to trigger the second fancybox inside your (pause) event callback like

```
function onPause() {
       froogaloop.addEvent('pause', function(data) {
                $('#example4').trigger("click"); //linkfunctionality you want to show
       });
 }
```

... that will bring the second content (`#demoView`) inside fancybox and the current (`#divVideo`) will just fade out.

Comment: problem solved ..... with the solution you proposed when i checked the files on the online server thanks alot!!!!!!!

Comment: one last question how can i put timer check before this event gets triggered --- $('#example4').trigger("click"); --- timer check like after 10 seconds...

Comment: you could use javascript `setTimeout`; something like: `setTimeout(function(){$("#example4").trigger("click");},10000);` where 1000 = 1 sec

Answer (score 0):

Is it now because the enclosing div for **demoView** is hidden? So something like...

```
$("#demoview").parent().css({'display','inherit'});
```

May work?

Answer (score 0):

Why is the parent even there? Perhaps you should do away with it and put the style attribute on your demoView div.

Comment: is there anyways to click up the div function by javascript like $('#divAB7').clicked; // to accomplish the following funcionality same done when clicked on Read more: <a href="#divAB7" class="btn1 fl">Read More</a>